# Why this code for Djikstra's algorithm shows a compilation error using a heap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long 
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair

vector<pair<int,int> > mygraph[100001];
int dist[100001];

void shortestpath(int n, int s);
class heapnode
{
public:
    int vertex;
    int key;
};

struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const heapnode &a, const heapnode &b)
    {
        if (a.key > b.key)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int main (void)
{
    int t,i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 100001; i++ )
        dist[i] = -1;
    int a,b,c;
    int foo,n,m,s,e;
    cin>>t;
    while (t != 0)
    {
        cin>>n>>m>>s>>e;
        foo = m;
        while (foo != 0)
        {
            cin>>a>>b>>c;
            mygraph[a].pb(mp(b,c));
            mygraph[b].pb(mp(a,c));
            foo--;
        }
        shortestpath(n,s);
        if (dist[e] == -1)
            cout<<"NONE\n";
        else
            cout<<dist[e]<<"\n";
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}

void shortestpath(int n, int s)
{
    vector<heapnode> myvec;
    myvec.resize(n);
    int i,j,val,weight;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        myvec[i].vertex = i;
        myvec[i].key = INT_MAX;
    }
    myvec[s].key = 0; // setting the source key to be 0 for Djikstra's
    bool visited[n+1];
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        visited[i] = false;  
    make_heap(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),comp());  // making a min heap
    vector<int> processedver;
    while (processedver.size() != n)
    {
        heapnode obj = myvec.front();  
        pop_heap(myvec.begin(),myvec.end()); // popping the front
        myvec.pop_back(); 
        processedver.pb(obj.vertex); // putting the popped vertex in processedver
        dist[obj.vertex] = obj.key; // setting the value of dist
        int u = obj.vertex; 
        visited[u] = true; // setting it to be true
        auto it = mygraph[u].begin(); 
        while (it != mygraph[u].end())  // updating the vertex neighbours
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (it->first == j)
                {
                    val = j;
                    weight = it->second;
                    break;
                }       
            }
            if (visited[val] != true && myvec[val].key > (dist[u]+weight))
            {
                myvec[val].key = dist[u]+weight;
            }
            make_heap(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),comp());
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have tried implementing the Dijkstra's algorithm using a min heap. I made a heapnode which contains the vertex number and a key number.

The above shows a compilation error. http://ideone.com/5VdCLQ

I know it's a problem with heap, but I am not able to find the problem properly.

Comment: You are able to use vectors, so why do you create an array of 100001 vectors? Why not a vector of vectors?

Comment: Make `cmp::operator()(...)` a `const` member function.

Comment: Those macros are **evil**. All somebody needs to do is create a function or variable called `ll` and boom. Doesn't compile.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I was solving a problem and the input size doesn't exceed 10^5, hence this. Though I will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @RSahu, what exactly should I do and please explain the reason for the same too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are stemming from the line

```
    pop_heap(myvec.begin(),myvec.end());
```

Since there is no `operator<` function for `heapnode`, you either implement it or pass a `comp` to `pop_heap` by changing it to

```
    pop_heap(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(), comp());
```

Comment: Will the `comp()` (see code I have posted) that I have made for making the heap work with pop_heap() too?

Comment: @rohansingh, yes. that's the only one you should use. It doesn't make sense to use one way of comparing two objects when calling `make_heap` and use a different way of comparing two objects when calling `pop_heap`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `operatr<()` for `class heapnode`, something like:

```
class heapnode
{
public:
    int vertex;
    int key;
    bool operator<(const heapnode& rhs) {
        return key < rhs.key;
    }
};
```

Comment: Will it be `key > rhs.key` if I wish to make a min-heap?

Comment: And it now shows a runtime error, see this: http://ideone.com/04bE7Z

Comment: @rohansingh It would make your `vector<heapnode> myvec` sort in descending rather than ascending order.  So it all depends on how  `make_heap` works.

Comment: @rohansingh I answered your OP, we're not here to totally debug your code.

Comment: @rohansingh, this goes back to my comment. You either use `comp` to both calls - `make_heap` and `pop_heap` - or omit the `comp` from both calls and use the `operator<` function.